# Lossless compression of Arabic book reviews from goodreads

Tags: compression, arabic, lossless-compression

For a project at my university, we are required to compress a dataset that holds 63,000 reviews from goodreads all written in Arabic.

---

After doing some preliminary research, I've found the best candidates to be LZW and Deflate algorithms. However, I am not sure if the algorithms' performance would decline when using non-English text, or when they're applied to short-medium length text (book reviews are not that long) as that kind of text wouldn't usually have high repeatability, and I'm not sure if using the same dictionary for all reviews is the best approach.
Anyone here who tackled a similar problem and knows a better way of compressing the data?

---

Note: What matters is the compression ratio, compression time is not relevant.

---

Note: the compressed files must be in binary form

Comment: For compression of text, you might want to look at [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about the algorithms that know anything about English. They are only looking for repeating strings and skewed statistics of symbols. There may be some impact with respect to the latter, due to coding the characters in multiple bytes as opposed to letters in a single byte. For the former, all languages repeat words and phrases, so you should get comparable compression.

I recommend that you use a UTF-8 representation of the text, which will best allow standard compressors to apply their byte-oriented approaches to compression.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer and advice, much appreciated.
I get that the algorithms don't know what language they're compressing, my question was rather if the nature of the language make an algorithm less efficient. For example, if the frequency of Arabic letters were closer to each other than those in English, my guess is Huffman code would yield worse results. That was mostly my concern.